# Comparing a number of single column excel files to specific nested list / tuples

Tags: python, excel, pandas, nested, nested-lists

I am after some advice please.
I have a tuple containing 30 nested elements (converted from a json response) 
in this format:

```
[('Group_1',['xyz123','str123','834hsj','nmp001','888tyu','abc123']),...('Group_30' ,['aaaa', 'bbb', 'fff'])
```

I have 5 excel files named after the 5 corresponding groups in the tuple plus their rows are as follow:

Excel xls file 1:
Name: Group_1
Content:

```
Column: A
Row1: Group_1
Row2: xyz123
Row3: str123
Row4: 834hsj
Row5: nmp001
Row6: 888tyu
Row7: abc123
```

Excel xls file 2:
Name: Group_2
Content:

> Row1: Group_2

etc up to Group_5

The aim is to compare the groups matching values between the elements in the tuple and excel files so that Group_1 to Group_5 in tuple plus nested list matches the contents of excel and its column contents. If there is a difference in the corresponding groups, then list the strings which are missing or outstanding and their location.

Would you recommend to import the excel files (which are all 1 column in size of different lengths) into panda as separate dataframes and break up the tuple into separate lists then also into panda dataframes ? Or Import the excel in data frames then convert into lists (1 per group) to compare to the tuple (which will have to be broken into groups lists.

Thanks

Comment: Does the order of the contents have to match?

Comment: No just the group name and string name within the group lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to read each file in a loop, turn each list into a set, 
and [get wild.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Basic_operations):

Assuming that you have your list of tuples in the list `groups`:

```
groups

[('Group_1',['xyz123','str123','834hsj','nmp001','888tyu','abc123']),
 ('Group_30' ,['aaaa', 'bbb', 'fff'])]
```

And you have files named with the group names like this:

```
Group_1.xls
Group_30.xls
```

First, read the XLS in, skipping the first row (i.e. 'A'), and setting the second row as the column name (i.e. 'Group_1').

```
for group in groups:
    df = pd.read_excel(group[0] + '.xls', header=0, skiprows=[0])
```

It should look like this:

```
df

  Group_1
0  xyz123
1  str123
2  834hsj
3  nmp001
4  888tyu
5  abc123
```

Then, we turn the elements from the file and list into sets and output the results:

```
for group in groups:
    df = pd.read_excel(group[0] + '.xls', header=0, skiprows=[0])

    file_set = set(df[group[0]].to_list())
    tup_set = set(group[1])

    print()
    print("In file and in tuple")
    print(file_set.intersection(tup_set))
    print("In file, but not in tuple")
    print(file_set.difference(tup_set))
    print("In tuple, but not in file")
    print(tup_set.difference(file_set))
```

You should get output like this:

```
In file and in tuple
{'nmp001', '834hsj', '888tyu', 'str123', 'abc123', 'xyz123'}
In file, but not in tuple
set()
In tuple, but not in file
set()

In file and in tuple
set()
In file, but not in tuple
{'nmp001', '834hsj', '888tyu', 'str123', 'abc123', 'xyz123'}
In tuple, but not in file
{'bbb', 'fff', 'aaaa'}
```

PS. `set()` is the empty set.

Comment: Thanks for the above. It's clear you've done this before so excuse the following trivial questions to allow me to test it out as I havent worked with sets or panda to this extent :    Q1. Did you mean to use group in "groups:" so that groups represents the path of my excel files (as in groups is declared before the code as groups = c:\\users\\*.xlsx ?   All the excel files are in separate files entities.  Q2. should I use pd.read_excel instead and they are not in csv or will pd.read_csv work anyway?. The above will get me started on testing your Answer. Thanks again.

Comment: And by the way the above list:

Comment: The element `group[0]` resolves to the first value in the tuple of each tuple that's a list element. (i.e. "Group_1") You need to use that to construct your file name. I added some comments explaining.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok so apologies, but I created exactly the setup described above only having Group_1.xls and Group_30.xls plus the groups list and the exact code and received this error:   KeyError 'Group_1' . Any ideas what could be happening? 
I added a print to check 
    `for group in groups:
        df = pd.read_excel(group[0] + '.xls', header=0, skiprows=[0])
        print(df)`
And get:

        xyz123
     0  str123
     1  834hsj
     2  nmp001
     3  888tyu
     4  abc123

Comment: currently using Jupyter but Im going to try VSCode to see if it can give me more info as to where it's going wrong.

Comment: Worked it out. It was my original display of the excel files having the first row showing as Column A. Group_1 or Group_X should be part of the comparison therefore skiprows was not needed. 
After removing skiprows the code works like a dream. 
Thanks again so much @Dave